# Cambiar la posición de un valor en un array, teniendo en cuenta la posicion de otro valor

Tags: java

el problema es el siguiente, estoy haciendo un pacman en Java que se muestra en la consola de netbeans, mediante una matriz formada por strings, el caso es que necesito que los fantasmas se muevan hacia el pacman.

El programa funciona con un bucle, en cada iteración te pide que te muevas una casilla con el pacman en cualquier dirección intentando no avanzar hacia la posicion de los fantasmas.

```
Scanner s=new Scanner (System.in);
    Random r=new Random();
    //matriz del laberinto
    String[][] laberinto={
        {"-","-","-","-","-","-","-","-","-","-"},
        {"|","m","m","m","m","m","m","m","m","|"},
        {"|","m","|","m","m","m","m","|","m","|"},
        {"|","m","-","|","m","m","|","-","m","|"},
        {"|","m","m","|","m","m","|","m","m","|"},
        {"|","m","m","|","☻","☻","|","m","m","|"},
        {"|","m","m","|","-","-","|","m","m","|"},
        {"|","m","m","m","m","m","☺","m","m","|"},
        {"|","m","m","m","m","m","m","m","m","|"},
        {"|","-","-","-","-","-","-","-","-","|"}};
    //Bucle para mostrar por pantalla el laberinto al iniciar
    int linea=0;
    for (int i = 0; i < laberinto.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < laberinto.length; j++) {
            if(linea==i){
                System.out.print(laberinto[i][j]+" ");
            }
        }
        linea++;
        System.out.println("");
    }
    //numero de monedas totales
    int nMonedas=47;
    //Posicion actual y anterior del PacMan
    int posicionVerticalPM=7;
    int posicionHorizontalPM=6;
    int posicionVerticalPmAnterior=posicionVerticalPM;
    int posicionHorizontalPmAnterior=posicionHorizontalPM;

    //Posicion actual y anterior del fantasma numero 1
    int posicionVerticalF1=5;
    int posicionHorizontalF1=4;
    int posicionVerticalFAnterior1=posicionVerticalF1;
    int posicionHorizontalFAnterior1=posicionHorizontalF1;

    //Posicion actual y anterior del fantasma numero 2
    int posicionVerticalF2=5;
    int posicionHorizontalF2=5;
    int posicionVerticalFAnterior2=posicionVerticalF2;
    int posicionHorizontalFAnterior2=posicionHorizontalF2;

    while(nMonedas>0){
        System.out.println("Muevete");
        String movimiento=s.nextLine();
        switch(movimiento){
            case "w":
                posicionVerticalPM--;
                posicionVerticalPmAnterior=posicionVerticalPM;
                posicionVerticalPmAnterior++;
                posicionHorizontalPmAnterior=posicionHorizontalPM;
                break;
            case "s":
                posicionVerticalPM++;
                posicionVerticalPmAnterior=posicionVerticalPM;
                posicionVerticalPmAnterior--;
                posicionHorizontalPmAnterior=posicionHorizontalPM;
                break;
            case "a":
                posicionHorizontalPM--;
                posicionHorizontalPmAnterior=posicionHorizontalPM;
                posicionHorizontalPmAnterior++;
                posicionVerticalPmAnterior=posicionVerticalPM;
                break;
            case "d":
                posicionHorizontalPM++;
                posicionHorizontalPmAnterior=posicionHorizontalPM;
                posicionHorizontalPmAnterior--;
                posicionVerticalPmAnterior=posicionVerticalPM;
                break;
        }
        switch(laberinto[posicionVerticalPM][posicionHorizontalPM]){
            case "m":
                laberinto[posicionVerticalPM][posicionHorizontalPM]="☺";
                laberinto[posicionVerticalPmAnterior][posicionHorizontalPmAnterior]=" ";
                nMonedas--;
                break;
            case "-":
                laberinto[posicionVerticalPM][posicionHorizontalPM]="-";
                posicionVerticalPM=posicionVerticalPmAnterior;
                posicionHorizontalPM=posicionHorizontalPmAnterior;
                laberinto[posicionVerticalPmAnterior][posicionHorizontalPmAnterior]="☺";
                break;
            case "|":
                laberinto[posicionVerticalPM][posicionHorizontalPM]="|";
                posicionVerticalPM=posicionVerticalPmAnterior;
                posicionHorizontalPM=posicionHorizontalPmAnterior;
                laberinto[posicionVerticalPmAnterior][posicionHorizontalPmAnterior]="☺";
                break;
            case "☻":
                System.out.println("");
                System.out.println("Se acabo, Has perdido...");
                System.exit(0);
                break;
            case " ":
                laberinto[posicionVerticalPM][posicionHorizontalPM]="☺";
                laberinto[posicionVerticalPmAnterior][posicionHorizontalPmAnterior]=" ";
                break;
        }

        linea=0;
        for (int i = 0; i < laberinto.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < laberinto.length; j++) {
                if(linea==i){
                    System.out.print(laberinto[i][j]+" ");
                }
            }
            linea++;
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }
    System.out.println("¡Enhorabuena! ¡Has Ganado!");
```

Comment: ¿Estás preguntando como cambiar un valor en un array? o ¿Estás preguntando como hacer una inteligencia artificial para los fantasmas?

Comment: la inteligencia artficiali

Comment: ¿Qué significan los símbolos del array?

Comment: la "m" son monedas los "-" y "|" son paredes, la cara blanca el pacman y las 2 negras los fantasmas

Comment: Tu código no compila debido a que donde dice `String movimiento = s.nextLine();` s no ha sido declarado, trata de poner siempre un [mcve]

Comment: Crear la inteligencia artificial de los fantasmas no es algo trivial, ¿qué has investigado o intentado hasta el momento? ¿Con qué errores/dificultades te estás encontrando? Lee [ask] y completa el [tour] para más información (y con ello ganarás tu primera medalla).

Comment: Ya esta el código completo.